# Complex sort with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

I'm new in Mongoose and I want to create a 'complex' sorting. So I have the following schemas:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    ...
    skills : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Skill' }]
});

var ProjectSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    ...
    skills : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Skill' }]
});

var SkillSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});
```

So given those schemas what I need is to sort by the matching percentage between   the user skills and the project skills, so basically I want to show first the projects that are more related to the user. Is that possible by using just mongoose? If so I guess I will need to create a sorting function that I can pass to the query or something.

Thank you!